# Specify architecture and Debug/Release modes in *nuspec file to publish a DLL C++ project

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuspec

I have a Visual Studio C++ project that creates a DLL for both x86 and x64 architectures in Debug and Release modes. I should publish this package as a nuget package with regards to these specifications. So I should have 4 DLLs in my package. My question is how to specify x86, x64 in my nuspec file. I was thinking whether it should be specified in the *target* field of each *file* but I can't find any documentation on how to exactly specify these specifications.
My nuspec file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <!-- Required elements-->
        <id>counterpartylookup</id>
        
        <version>0.0.0</version>
        
        <description>counterpartylookup/v140/win32/x86/x64</description>
        
        <authors>***</authors>

        <!-- Optional elements -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <owners>...</owners>
        
        <licenseUrl>***</licenseUrl>
        
        <projectUrl>***</projectUrl>
        
        <dependencies>
            ***
        </dependencies>
        
        <tags> {vc140, win32, x64, x86, dynamic, C++, native}</tags>
    </metadata>

        <files>
            <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x64\Release\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="lib" />
            <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x64\Debug\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="lib" />
             <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x86\Release\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="lib" />
             <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x86\Debug\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="lib" />
        </files>
    <!-- Optional 'files' node -->
</package>
```

Comment: Did you want to reference this c++ nuget package based on the specific platform on net project?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to specify x86, x64 in my nuspec file.

You need to place the dlls in a folder named runtimes within sub-folders named {platform}-{architecture}\lib{framework} or {platform}-{architecture}\native.

The folder structure:

```
  \runtimes
    \x86
        \Debug
              \Release
    \x64
        \Debug
              \Release
```

The nuspec file is like:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x64\Release\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="runtimes\ x64\Release " />
    <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x64\Debug\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target=" runtimes\ x64\Debug " />
     <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x86\Release\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target=" runtimes\ x86\Release " />
     <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x86\Debug\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target=" runtimes\ x86\Debug " />
</files>
```

The related documents: [Architecture-specific folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#architecture-specific-folders) and [Adding the native implementation libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-packages#adding-the-native-implementation-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try another:

**1)** create a file called `<package_id>.targets` file in your project folder. **In your side**, you should name it as `counterpartylookup.targets`:

write these under it:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64' and '$(Cofiguration)'=='Debug'">
        <Reference Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Reference\x64\Debug\CounterPartyLookup.dll"></Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x86' and '$(Cofiguration)'=='Debug'">
        <Reference Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Reference\x86\Debug\CounterPartyLookup.dll"></Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64' and '$(Cofiguration)'=='Release'">
        <Reference Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Reference\x64\Release\CounterPartyLookup.dll"></Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x86' and '$(Cofiguration)'=='Release'">
        <Reference Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Reference\x86\Release\CounterPartyLookup.dll"></Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**2)** modify your nuspec file:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x64\Release\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="Reference\x64\Release" />
    <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x64\Debug\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="Reference\x64\Debug" />
     <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x86\Release\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="Reference\x86\Release" />
     <file src="..\shared\v140\bin\x86\Debug\CounterPartyLookup.dll" target="Reference\x86\Debug" />
     <file src="counterpartylookup.targets" target="build"/>
</files>
```

**3)** repack your c++ project and then before you install the new one, you should delete all nuget caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`